# Aggregate columns based on certain value in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to e.g. aggregate all values of D2 for indiv 0? It is important to me to know the total habitat area (HabArea) and percentage of a certain habitat type (D2), so it would be easier for me if I could all the values for D2 of indiv 0 together. I hope this is possible.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to use the [`sum()`-function](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=sum#sum)?

Comment: Yes, but how I should use it is unclear to me.

Comment: I cannot open the link you link to unfortunately

Comment: I suggest head for the official QGIS tutorial and search for "sum" - or check the examples in the field calculator.